# PHP's "\t" doesn't work in the Inspector. How can I check it?

Tags: php, wordpress

Okay so I played around with PHP's indentation levels but it seems that this only works for content and not for HTML elements. I mean, they might work indeed also for HTML elements, but they display in the Google Chrome Inspector exactly the same way whether I use the indentation "\t" or not. Why is this and how can I test it also for HTML code? This is for trying to understand Wordpress' Walker way of outputting HTML.
[Click here to see code + output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RRQA.png)

Comment: Use htmlentities like `&nbsp;`

Comment: Or set `white-space: pre;` on those elements, maybe.

Comment: Chrome's inspector renders its own view of the HTML element tree. If you want to see if your code is generating spaces or tabs, right-click the page and view the source.